# This API Endpoint code works fine in Express but gvies error when implemented in next js

Tags: typescript, express, next.js

Express Code:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const devices = await gsmarena.catalog.getBrand("apple-phones-48");
    const name = devices.map((device) => device.name);
    res.json(name);
})
```

Nextjs Code:

```
import {gsmarena} from "gsmarena-api"

export async function GET() {
  const devices = await gsmarena.catalog.getBrand("apple-phones-48");
  const name = devices.map((device: any) => device.name);
   
    return Response.json({ data: any })
  }
```

When using the same code in nextjs it gives error:

```
 ⨯ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'catalog')
    at GET (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/phonelist/route.ts:9:78)
    at D:\WEB D\specsync\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:63815
    at D:\WEB D\specsync\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\trace\tracer.js:133:36
    ...
```

I tried it in react also it is giving the same error

I am using the Gsm aren api from here : https://github.com/nordmarin/gsmarena-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'catalog')` means that the value of `gsmarena` is undefined on line 4 of your next.js code.

Looking at the documentation for the `gsmarena-api` package, it looks like that package doesn't have a named export and you probably want the default export instead.

```
// Instead of import { gsmarena } from 'gsmarena-api';
import gsmarena from 'gsmarena-api';
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, man. This really frustrated me for straight 2 hrs.